# Using FPDF and PHP, is there a way to mix characters from two fonts in one cell? I'd like one Symbol character in a normal text string

Tags: php, fonts, fpdf

I'm using PHP with FPDF to create PDF files. I'm trying to print the Greek rho symbol (an 'r' in the Symbol font) in a regular string of ASCII text. I can put it in a cell by itself using SetFont() but cannot figure out if there is such a thing as a mixed-font string.

I can create a cell with some text, then a cell with the Symbol font character, then another cell with the following text. The spacing looks all wrong though no matter how I try to justify the text in the cells.

```
$pdf->Cell(35,14,'+/- 5m','LT',0,'R');
$pdf->SetFont('Symbol','',8);
$pdf->Cell(5,14,'r','T',0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->Cell(60,14,' peak to peak','TR',0,'L');
```

## I want this to output '+/- 5mp peak to peak' where the Greek rho symbol is substituted for the p in the mp. It means 'millirho'.

I end up with about an 'em' space separating the 'm' and the rho symbol where I would like no space at all.

## It ends up looking like '+/- 5m  p peak to peak'.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out an ugly hard-coded workaround:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->Cell(100,14,'+/- 5m   peak to peak','LTR',0,'C');
# now back up and print a rho symbol in the right place
$x = $pdf->GetX(); $y = $pdf->GetY(); $pdf->SetXY($x-69.5,$y-0.5);
$pdf->SetFont('Symbol','',9); $pdf->Cell(5,14,'r'); 
$pdf->SetXY($x,$y);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8); # restore original font
```

But if I change anything in the form related to font size, etc. this will have to be redone too.

Comment: Look into using the `GetStringWidth` method of fPDF to determine where to position things. The method takes the font and its size into account.